# display poll questions after buyer places an order in magento

Tags: checkout, forms

After buyer completes transaction ("place an  order"), I want to provide an option for "survey" or "poll" about the site.

So I can know about the buyer's satisfaction about our site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can magento default pull function survey.
See Here http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-configure-and-use-polls

`Step1:` Create option at poll from

`Step2:`call the poll option at order success page mean checkout/onepage/success pae

Comment: hi,
thanks a lot for reply.

can you please give me the code for success.phtml file to ask polls....


/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout > success.phtml

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply.


I got polls in sucess page. as i created 4 polls i called 4 "poll id" in success.phtml page.

so 4 polls are displaying.

but after i voted for 1 poll, it displayed the result as follows:

SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY

You have no items in your shopping cart.

Click here to continue shopping.

but I want to vote for all 4 polls and than it should display the result as follows :

"Thanks for voting".

if you want see demo of how it's working, you can check here : http://kidsdial.com/

here you can see the code of success.phtml file = http://pastebin.com/CY2eqcpN

Comment: I am busy now,Will reply shortly